# Trim text using CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, accordion

I am using a css class to trim my text in the accordion header. The header contains two fields. One URL and the other some plain text. I need to display them both in the same line.

Expected Output:

> .../abc/xyz Count:42

Actual output:

> .../abc/xyz Count:42/

(I am getting this weird slash at the end of the entire text whereas it should be at the end of the URL. )

My CSS class is this:

```css
.trim-info {
    max-width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:left;
    text-overflow:ellipsis ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;  
    position: relative;
    direction:rtl;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

My code in the webpage is:

```html
 <accordion-heading >
     <article class="trim-info">{{item1}} <b> Count:</b>{{item2}} </article>
 </accordion-heading >
```

Could you please help me with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just to point out a typo, the last end tag should be `</accordion-heading>`.

Comment: I just created a fiddle... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the css property text-overflow: has the wrong syntax.

Try `text-overflow:ellipsis;`

http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/4541/

Check also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

The issue was on direction:rtl; :)

Comment: The output you are getting it's because of your js. How do you get that string or better what string do you get in input? .../abc/xyz Count:42/ This just reverse the text direction with direction:rtl; so it's something that your js outputs and then the css changes the direction.

Comment: Thank you so much for the above comment. I will probably have to change the display order. The '/' is getting appended after the text is reversed.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. You can accept the answer if you want :)